# difference between spark read textFile and csv

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a text file delimited by |. I am trying this

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").csv("/tmp/file.txt").show()
```

I am only reading/seeing only the header but no data.

When I try the same with textFile, I am getting data but all in one column

```
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").textFile("/tmp/file.txt").show()
```

Is there a way to read data via csv? I am using spark 2.4.4

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: I am running it in an emr cluster

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue was the file is in UTF16 so I had to convert it and do run dostounix on it. Thanks for your advice. Apologies I really did not know that